# Can I use a keystore created by Java keytool to encrypt data in Android SDK?

Tags: java, android, cryptography, keystore

I'm getting the standard keystore used in Android Dev by using the instructions in the Android Docs:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

It's obviously used to sign my apk, but can I also load "my-release-key.keystore" into the Android SDK and use it to encrypt/decrypt data?

I'm having difficulty doing this using this method:

```
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(keystoreFile);
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keystore.load(is, "password".toCharArray());
```

I receive this error:

> java.io.IOException: Wrong version of key store.

Comment: A wild guess, but perhaps the JKS format changed after Java 6 (which Android still uses) and you generated the keystore with a later version. Also, you should probably do `KeyStore.getInstance("JKS")` rather than use the default type, as it may be different on Android.

Comment: Unless you plan on having the user enter the passphrases for the keystore and key, baking the keystore into your app will be useless. I could decompile your app and retrieve the passphrase. Worse, you are now allowing other developers to create apps that are signed by your signing key, such as hacked upgrades to this app.

Comment: I did this and I got the following error:  java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore JKS implementation. I've read that Android doesn't support JKS anymore.

Comment: So Android has indeed changed to BKS format which is not compatible with JKS. Not sure if my use case is possible any more then.

Comment: Have you tried the "wild guess" of ntoskrnl? I would rather call it "educated guess" myself.

Comment: Hello. I did bake my keystore file in Android Studio. Doesn't sound like a smart thing. At least, my app is not published yet. How can I access my keystore if it wont be baked in my Android studio project. Should I save this file in some online database and download it from there? How can I create the fileInputStream("mykeystore") where should my "keystore" be? for now its a file inside a directory in my documents in my PC. thanks @CommonsWare

Comment: @i_o: The OP wanted to use the same keystore used to sign the app for other signing functionality within the app. That was a mistake. The OP should use separate keystores. Having a keystore packaged in an app is not a problem, but having the keystore used to sign the app packaged in the app is a problem.